# How to make Terrain Convex Hull Collision?

Tags: modeling, mesh, scripting, physics, collision

I'm trying to make Convex collision for terrain, and I cant seem to get it correct.

I want to keep low datablocks if possible but I'd also like it to be very accurate. I've tried using VHACD to make the convex hulls but it wasn't very accurate and took a very long time. Especially since I have to put the convex hulls in a group for the program I'm using for these hulls to recognize.

Any way to make it?

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, it and like the best thing to do would be to set the collision type to 'mesh', by to have a relatively low poly-count on the terrain mesh. Why do you need to use a convex Hull?

Comment: I have to use a convex hull because the engine I use only recognizes convex as collision. I'd like to keep a low poly count but I wouldn't mind it too much if its not too high.

Comment: Still need help? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry dude, I got nothing 